# Making a drop down div overlap content div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a small issue, I've made a example to help convey what's going wrong and what i'm trying to achieve. So as you can see there is a header with one button and below some content. Now when you hover over this button a drop down is then displayed, however it isn't sitting in the position i wanted it to be. Which is just below the header and overlapping the content. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be amazing.

Thanks.

```js
$("#ddBtn").hover(function() {
  $("#dropdown").toggle();
});
```

```css
.ddBtn{
  margin:20px;
  float:right;
}
.pageBtns{
  display:block;
  margin:20px;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height:60px;
  background-color:#333;
}
#page{
  border:2px solid #999;
}
#dropdown{
  float:right;
  background-color:#d6d6d6;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <button id="ddBtn"class="ddBtn">Drop Down</button>
</div>
<div id="page">
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. ﻿no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. ﻿no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. ﻿no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. ﻿no great but music too old found arose.</p>
</div>
<div id="dropdown" class="hidden">
  <button class="pageBtns">Page1</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page2</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page3</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page4</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: if you add `position:absolute; left:10%; top:10%` to the header, it will reside 10% from the topleft of your browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you hover on the button , it shows the menu. But when you remove the cursor ,it disappears. So that thing you won't to do. that's why you use a click event to show the menu and click again to hide.

```js
$("#ddBtn").hover(function() {
  $("#dropdown").toggle();
});

//if you want to keep dropdownmenu after appearing then you can use this.

/*$("#ddBtn").click(function() {
  $("#dropdown").toggle();
});*/
```

```css
.ddBtn{
  margin:20px;
  float:right;
}
.pageBtns{
  display:block;
  margin:20px;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height:60px;
  background-color:#333;
}
#page{
  border:2px solid #999;
}
#dropdown{
  background-color:#d6d6d6;
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  right:3%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <button id="ddBtn"class="ddBtn">Drop Down</button>
</div>
<div id="dropdown" class="hidden">
  <button class="pageBtns">Page1</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page2</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page3</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page4</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page5</button>
</div>
<div id="page">
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. no great but music too old found arose.</p>
</div>
```

Is this the same that you want?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant thanks for the assistance, i'll mark it as the answer asap. Thanks again.

Comment: It is always better for later visitors if you explain how your code answers the question. A code dump only helps the OP copy and paste their way out of their problem, but does not help them understand the solution so that they don't need to ask again.

Comment: i have updated my answer. so from that I hope every one can understand , how the code works and will be helpful to them to understand. in case of any suggestion or my mistake, I would love to correct my answer.

Comment: @G.Hamton .Glad to help you. Hope you got your output as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

When you're working with drop downs, you generally are going to use relative/absolute positioning.

```js
$("#ddBtn").hover(function() {
  $("#dropdown").toggle();
});
```

```css
.ddBtn{
  margin:20px;
  float:right;
}
.pageBtns{
  display:block;
  margin:20px;
}
#header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height:60px;
  background-color:#333;
}
#page{
  border:2px solid #999;
}
#dropdown{
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top:100%;
  background-color:#d6d6d6;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <button id="ddBtn"class="ddBtn">Drop Down</button>
  
<div id="dropdown" class="hidden">
  <button class="pageBtns">Page1</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page2</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page3</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page4</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page5</button>
</div>
</div>
<div id="page">
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. ﻿no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. ﻿no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. ﻿no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. ﻿no great but music too old found arose.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I am getting is, you want to show list of pages on hover so that user can select from those pages. Then not only you have to show div containing links to pages under dropdown button, but you also need to make sure it remains there for users to make some action.

I have made some changes to your css and jquery, have a try with them

```js
$("#ddBtn").hover(function() {
  $("#dropdown").toggle();
});
$("#dropdown").mouseenter(function() {
   $("#dropdown").show();
});
$("#dropdown").mouseleave(function() {
   $("#dropdown").hide();
});
```

```css
.ddBtn{
  margin:20px;
  float:right;
}
.pageBtns{
  display:block;
  margin:20px;
}
#header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height:60px;
  background-color:#333;
}
#page{
  border:2px solid #999;
}
#dropdown{
  float:right;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:10;
  top:42px;
  right:20px;
  background-color:#d6d6d6;
  display: none;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <button id="ddBtn"class="ddBtn">Drop Down</button>
  
<div id="dropdown" class="hidden">
  <button class="pageBtns">Page1</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page2</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page3</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page4</button>
  <button class="pageBtns">Page5</button>
</div>
</div>
<div id="page">
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. no great but music too old found arose.</p>
  <p>Received the likewise law graceful his. Nor might set along charm now equal green. Pleased yet equally correct colonel not one. Say anxious carried compact conduct sex general nay certain. Mrs for recommend exquisite household eagerness preserved now. My improved honoured he am ecstatic quitting greatest formerly. 

Ladies others the six desire age. Bred am soon park past read by lain. As excuse eldest no moment. An delight beloved up garrets am cottage private. The far attachment discovered celebrated decisively surrounded for and. Sir new the particular frequently indulgence excellence how. Wishing an if he sixteen visited tedious subject it. Mind mrs yet did quit high even you went. Sex against the two however not nothing prudent colonel greater. Up husband removed parties staying he subject mr. 

Unfeeling so rapturous discovery he exquisite. Reasonably so middletons or impression by terminated. Old pleasure required removing elegance him had. Down she bore sing saw calm high. Of an or game gate west face shed. no great but music too old found arose.</p>
</div>
```